# In an array of obects watched with Vue-watch, how to get index of object that was changed?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, watch, computed-properties

I have an array of objects, like this:

```
 myArray: [{
 name: "First",
 price: 10,
 rebate: 5,
 listPrice: 15,
 outcome: 0
 },{
 name: "Second",
 price: 11,
 rebate: 5,
 listPrice: 16,
 outcome: 0
}
```

**I want to recalculate the `outcome`-value whenever any of the other values in the same object change.**

I already have a setup like this, but it looks for changes in any object and then recalculates the whole array. I've managed to set this up by using a combination of `computed` and `watch` functions. However they watch the whole array for changes and then recalculate the outcome-value for all objects in the array.

How can I watch for changes and then recalculate *only the changed object*?

Below is my current functions for recalculating the whole array (watching another property), but what I'm looking for could be completely different.

computed:

```
myArrayWasChanged() {
return [this.myArray.reduce((a, {vendors}) => a + vendors, 0), this.myArray.filter(item => item.discounted == false).length]
```

watch:

```
myArrayWasChanged: {
handler: function (val, oldVal) {
this.recalculateIsVendor();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `outcome` is completely dependent on the other properties, it isn't really part of the component's state. Thus, in the component's `data` you could store the array without the `outcome`, and then calculate a new version of the array *with the outcome* as a computed property.

```
data: function () {
  return {
    myArrayWithoutOutcome: [
    {
      name: "First",
      price: 10,
      rebate: 5,
      listPrice: 15
    },
    {
      name: "Second",
      price: 11,
      rebate: 5,
      listPrice: 16
    }]
  }
},
computed: {
  myArrayWithOutcome: function () {
    return this.myArrayWithoutOutcome.map(x => {
      return {...x, outcome: this.calculateOutcome(x)}
    })
  }
},
methods: {
  calculateOutcome(item) {
    // Logic to calculate outcome from item goes here
    return 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it does indeed work. It wasn't the solution I had imagined but I guess I need to learn :-)

Comment: If I wanted to add `outcome` to original array, rather than creating a new array. Could I still use this method somehow?

Comment: Computed properties shouldn’t modify data, so you’d probably have to achieve this using watches. That solution sounds quite risky - if at all possible I’d try to avoid putting calculated values in component data as it’s too easy for them to get out of sync.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yeah this was kind of my original question with watchers :-)